# Wordpress: How to use autowrap with <p> only in posts

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress page has now default autowrap with `<p>` settings.

Now I need to allow autowrapping only in **POSTS** not in **PAGES**. So all pages will have disabled autowrapping and only in **POSTS** I will have autowrapping enabled.

I tried to add this in `functions.php` but it doesn't work:

```
if( is_page() ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Is there any option how to disabled autowrapping on only **PAGES** and keep enabled only in **POSTS**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to can your `remove_filter` code using a higher priority than `wpautop` is currently called, so that it gets removed *before* it can get called. The default priority for wppautop is 10, so the following code will call it with priority 1:

```
function remove_autop_for_pages_only( $content ){
    /* Check if we are on a page, then remove wpautop */
    if( is_page() ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
    }
    return $content;
}
/* Call our function with priority 1 */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_autop_for_pages_only', 1 );
```